# Unambiguous CFG that generates regular language according to Pumping Lemma?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

The [pumping lemma for regular languages states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages):

> Specifically, the pumping lemma says that for any regular language L there exists a constant p such that any word w in L with length at least p can be split into three substrings, w = xyz, where the middle portion y must not be empty, such that the words xz, xyz, xyyz, xyyyz, … constructed by repeating y an arbitrary number of times (including zero times) are still in L.

Now what's the unambigious CFG that produces this (recognizes strings of the form $xy^kz$)?

if $x=z=a$ and $y=b$, then

$X \rightarrow aX | Xa | bX | Xb | a | b$

is ambiguous.

Comment: Please make sure you know what you want to ask *before* posting. Wasting people's time by changing your question in fundamental ways is not nice.

Comment: The Pumping lemma does not claim the existence of such a grammar. But since these words are all in the language L (*that* is the claim), just use any grammar for L. It remains to see why there are always unambiguous grammars for regular languages, but that's not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, *do* check out the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). It is quite different from what you state.

For the second one, it is the set of strings of $a$ with exactly one $b$. Use:

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow a S \mid b A \mid b \\
A &\rightarrow a A \mid a
\end{align}$

Clearly non-ambiguous. Even a regular grammar.

Comment: Is my sentence about the pumping lemma really incorrect?

Comment: @mavavilj, yes.

Comment: Then what does: "Specifically, the pumping lemma says that for any regular language L there exists a constant p such that any word w in L with length at least p can be split into three substrings, w = xyz, where the middle portion y must not be empty, such that the words xz, xyz, xyyz, xyyyz, … constructed by repeating y an arbitrary number of times (including zero times) are still in L." mean?

Comment: @mavavilj, you see the statemement is *significantly* longer, with a lot of qualifications.

Comment: The grammar you give does not seem to match e.g. $abba$. Only $a^kb$ or $b^ka$

Comment: @mavavilj, corrected the gramar. In any case, your grammar doesn't generate $abba$, and mine didn't generate what you state either.

Comment: Yeah because I couldn't figure out that without an $\epsilon$ -rule. Feel free to modify the grammar in question.

Comment: Even the new one doesn't generate $abba$ or $ab^ka$.

Comment: @mavavilj, sorry I won't run around chasing your ever changing question.

Comment: the question is about a CFG for regular language according to the pumping lemma. The language according to pumping lemma is of strings of the form $xy^kz$?